# Powershell: Cannot create credentials file with for dot-slash user

Tags: powershell, credentials

I am trying to run a remote command to a computer which has a ".\".

When I am trying the credentials using get-credentials and storing them to a file, I am not allowed to do. 
When I try to do using

```
$Username = -join($env:COMPUTERNAME,'\<user_name>')
$Password = '<password>'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
Invoke-Command -ComputerName  <computer_name> -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Cred  {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk}
```

I get the following error

```
Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occured while using Kerberos authenticati
on: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.  
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

But when I do a mstsc and use the same credentials it works.

Please let me know the way around.

Comment: Are you sure, that you need to auth with kerberos? You're using the computername as domain name, that seems counter intuitive to me.

Comment: This code is run in PS2, I tried doing .\<user_name> but same result. I used Kerberos for the authenticating, rather I found this to be used in powershell 4.

Comment: The account you're using is a local account, and not a domain account, right?

Comment: yes, local to the remote computer not a domain.

Comment: Then you have to use a different authentication method, as kerberos implicitly tries a domain authentication (which will not work). When you omit the parameter `Authentication`, you might get a step further. We'll see then, if you need to configure your local system to trust the system you're connecting to. But one step at a time. Try to go without `-authentication`

Comment: Omitting authentication parameter works in powershell 2 and can connect to all machines having powershell 2. But there are some machines with powershell 4 which doesnot work. Also when the command is run from powershell 4 it doesnot work without authentication. Do we have a way out of this?

Comment: What's your error message? Something with `trusted hosts`?

Comment: No, The same error that I get above. Running Test-wsman <computer_name> shows 
    `wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
    ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
    ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
    ProductVersion  : OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0`

Comment: Please add a description of your envirment to your question: What system you are conntecting from, to what system. Where are domain cred, where are local creds, where's domain joined and where not, etc.

Comment: I am managing a system of around 42 windows machines. 
Out of 42 about 35 machines have powershell 2 installed and all of the respond back when I use the command without credentials. The rest ones have powershell 4. All of them are accessible by rdc and I have to do work on manually on the rest 7. I want to set up a script on one machine that would collect the information I need and mail me the information I need.

Answer (score 0):

`$env:COMPUTERNAME` is ***your*** computer name!

Imagine I'm using ComputerA and wantning to connect to ComputerB as a local user on ComputerB.

Your code, as it currently stands is trying to connect as `ComputerA\Username`, which doesn't exist on ComputerB!

Comment: When I do a RDC (using mstsc) from computerA I see the same computerA\username. I have also tried to use computerB/<username> from powershell but it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing the username in below syntax?

```
$Username = -join('Localhost','\<user_name>')
```